# Javascript Regex replacing multiple groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace multiple matched groups based on a regex like this

```
var paramRegex = /{\s*\[(\w*)\]\s*(\w*)\s*\(([\w\s]*)\)\s*}/i; 
// should match {[group1] group2 (group3)}
var emptyParam = '{[]()}';

emptyParam.replace(paramRegex, 'a $1 b $2 c $3');
```

why does this result in 'a b c' ? Why have the brackets, curly braces and parantheses disappeared ?

I was expecting this to print '{[a]b(c)}'

Comment: Because braces are not captured.

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding: you do not replace the captured contents, you replace the *whole match*. Braces and parentheses are matched and *consumed*, thus, they are replaced.

Comment: So I have to capture basically everything in order to achieve what I want ? There's no way to just replace the captured groups and keep everything else the same ?

Comment: You need to capture what you need to keep. Or add the braces and parentheses back "manually", see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iy52NO/1)

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When replacing, we usually match *and capture* what we need to keep (to be able to refer to the captured values with backreferences) and only match what you do not need to keep.

In your case, you need to just put the punctuation into the replacement pattern:

```
.replace(/{\s*\[(\w*)\]\s*(\w*)\s*\(([\w\s]*)\)\s*}/g, "{[a]$1b$2(c)$3)}")
                                                        ^^ ^     ^ ^  ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBtjKO/1)