# Can you replace multiple captured groups at once?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I had a quick question about Regular Expressions. I'm fairly new to them so I was wondering, would I be able to replace different captured groups with different strings simultaneously? For instance, if I wanted to replace `/(ant)(dolphin)/` with `"insect"` for the group 'ant' and `"mammal"` for the group 'dolphin', would it be possible to replace them both at once?

Comment: See [Javascript Regex replacing multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183166/javascript-regex-replacing-multiple-groups)

Comment: The 2 capturing groups `(ant)(dolphin)` like that will match antdolphin. If you want to replace the separate words you might use a wordboundary and replace `str.replace(/\bant\b/g, "insect").replace(/\bdolphin\b/g, "mammal")`

Comment: Ok thank you! Much appreciated